# AVAudioPlayer stops playing the audio when iPhone goes to sleep

Tags: iphone

I need to play a background sound all the time as long as my application is running. I tried to use AVAudioPlayer for this purpose. However, it stops playing the sound as soon as the iPhone goes to sleep mode.

Could you  let me know how can I fix this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/908469/playing-a-sound-using-ipod-application

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may need to set an audio session category.  From the "iPhone Application Programming Guide"

> A category is a key that identifies a
>   set of audio behaviors for your
>   application. By setting a category,
>   you indicate your audio intentions to
>   iPhone OS, such as whether your audio
>   should continue when the screen locks.

The details about each category are listed at "[Audio Session Categories](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/AudioSessionCategories/AudioSessionCategories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007875-CH4)"

Answer (score 4):

In your particular example you may try the following. It should work right out of the box.

```
// Registers this class as the delegate of the audio session.
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setDelegate: self];    
// Allow the app sound to continue to play when the screen is locked.
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

well this solution may also be helpfull

```
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setDelegate: self]; 
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil]; 
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];
```

referenced from
http://www.mindyourcode.com/ios/iphone/how-to-play-audio-in-iphone-sleep-mode/