# iPhone - AVAudioSession - AVAudioRecorder - issues when device sleeps

Tags: avaudiorecorder, avaudiosession

I'm trying to figure out how to keep AVAudioRecorder recording even if the device goes to sleep (or to keep the device from going to sleep to begin with).

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/908359/avaudioplayer-stops-playing-the-audio-when-iphone-goes-to-sleep) I just need to add a [category](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/AudioSessionCategories/AudioSessionCategories.html) to the AVAudioSession, but that doesn't seem to be working.

I also found [MMPDeepSleepPreventer](https://github.com/marcop/MMPDeepSleepPreventer#) but every time it plays a silent sound it interrupts the recording.

So is there a way to get AVAudioRecorder to continue recording after the device sleeps. OR is there a way to stop the device from sleeping in the first place?

---

```
AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[audioSession setCategory :AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:NULL];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can stop the device from sleeping by adding
[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = YES;
But I am not sure whether Apple encourage using this.